# Default lxc networking suddenly stops to work

Tags: linux, networking, lxc

I've recently installed lxc on ubuntu 14.04.
Networking used to work (lxcbr0 being a NAT interface, DHCP configured using dnsmasq) but after a container restart, the networking does not work any more. No further IP's are assigned, neither are the containers linked to lxcbr0.
I've tried to purge and reinstall lxc, neither did that help.
Following are container and network configurations

```
NAME  STATE    IPV4  IPV6  AUTOSTART  
------------------------------------
znc   RUNNING  -     -     NO
```

ip link and ifconfig

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 52:54:81:57:7b:97  
     inet Adresse:x.x.x.x  Bcast:46.38.245.255  Maske:255.255.254.0
     inet6-Adresse: xy       Gültigkeitsbereich:Verbindung
     UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
     RX-Pakete:478039 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
     TX-Pakete:12195 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
     Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000
     RX-Bytes:142734376 (142.7 MB)  TX-Bytes:1930229 (1.9 MB)

lo        Link encap:Lokale Schleife  
     inet Adresse:127.0.0.1  Maske:255.0.0.0
     inet6-Adresse: ::1/128 Gültigkeitsbereich:Maschine
     UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metrik:1
     RX-Pakete:44 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
     TX-Pakete:44 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
     Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:0
     RX-Bytes:2864 (2.8 KB)  TX-Bytes:2864 (2.8 KB)

lxcbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse fe:f7:54:76:df:66  
     inet Adresse:10.0.3.1  Bcast:10.0.3.255  Maske:255.255.255.0
     inet6-Adresse: fe80::ac8b:6fff:fe2b:5e92/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Verbindung
     UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
     RX-Pakete:59 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
     TX-Pakete:50 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
     Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:0
     RX-Bytes:11272 (11.2 KB)  TX-Bytes:9651 (9.6 KB)

vethJDA1JG Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse fe:f7:54:76:df:66  
     inet6-Adresse: fe80::fcf7:54ff:fe76:df66/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Verbindung
     UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
     RX-Pakete:29 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Fenster:0
     TX-Pakete:19 Fehler:0 Verloren:0 Überläufe:0 Träger:0
     Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000
     RX-Bytes:6014 (6.0 KB)  TX-Bytes:4090 (4.0 KB)

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether xy
3: lxcbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default
link/ether fe:f7:54:76:df:66 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: vethJDA1JG: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master lxcbr0 state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether fe:f7:54:76:df:66 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

container configuration and log

```
# Template used to create this container:   /usr/share/lxc/templates/lxc-ubuntu
# Parameters passed to the template:
# For additional config options, please look at lxc.container.conf(5)

# Common configuration
lxc.include = /usr/share/lxc/config/ubuntu.common.conf

# Container specific configuration
lxc.rootfs = /var/lib/lxc/znc/rootfs
lxc.mount = /var/lib/lxc/znc/fstab
lxc.utsname = znc
lxc.arch = amd64

# Network configuration
lxc.network.type = veth
lxc.network.flags = up
lxc.network.link = lxcbr0
lxc.network.hwaddr = 00:16:3e:d2:db:d6


lxc-start 1437823814.247 DEBUG    lxc_cgmanager - cgmanager.c:cgm_setup_limits:1245 - cgroup 'devices.allow' set to 'c 10:228 rwm'
  lxc-start 1437823814.247 DEBUG    lxc_cgmanager - cgmanager.c:cgm_setup_limits:1245 - cgroup 'devices.allow' set to 'c 10:232 rwm'
  lxc-start 1437823814.247 INFO     lxc_cgmanager - cgmanager.c:cgm_setup_limits:1249 - cgroup limits have been setup
  lxc-start 1437823814.247 INFO     lxc_apparmor - lsm/apparmor.c:apparmor_process_label_set:157 - changed apparmor profile to lxc-container-default
  lxc-start 1437823814.248 NOTICE   lxc_start - start.c:start:1152 - exec'ing '/sbin/init'
 lxc-start 1437823814.252 NOTICE   lxc_start - start.c:post_start:1163 - '/sbin/init' started with pid '22703'
 lxc-start 1437823814.252 WARN     lxc_start - start.c:signal_handler:295 - invalid pid for SIGCHLD
 lxc-start 1437823814.252 DEBUG    lxc_commands - commands.c:lxc_cmd_handler:888 - peer has disconnected
 lxc-start 1437823814.256 DEBUG    lxc_commands - commands.c:lxc_cmd_get_state:574 - 'znc' is in 'RUNNING' state
 lxc-start 1437823814.257 DEBUG    lxc_commands - commands.c:lxc_cmd_handler:888 - peer has disconnected
```